# Max (entry_date) doesn't return last date

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table like this:

```
    entry_time student class grade
    ------------------------------
    1433793600 Dave    1      A
    1433793600 Sue     1      B
    1434994097 Dave    1      C
    1434994097 Sue     1      B
```

I'm using this command:

```
SELECT *, MAX(entry_time) from records GROUP BY student
```

I'm getting the first records for each student instead of the last. I've tried using MIN (entry_time) and get the same thing.

Comment: Are all classes '1'? If so, why bother storing that information at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using this query:

```
select * from 
record r 
where entry_time in 
(select max(entry_time) from record s where s.student = r.student group by student)
```

Comment: Looks okay for me if I understand the opener correctly: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b9a5/1

Comment: Note that a correlated subquery will be slow for larger data sets, but techincally I can see no problem with this solution (other than it ignores 'class', obviously)

Comment: Yea it has performance impact, but I tried my best to come up with correct solution. thanks @Strawberry pointing out and guiding :)

Comment: Well, take a look at the link Barmar's provided above. The uncorrelated query solution is likely to be as fast as anything.

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
select *,mdate from records a
join (
SELECT student, MAX(entry_time) as mdate
from records GROUP BY student) a on a.student=b.student and a.entry_time=b.entry_time
```

Comment: Because your answer is slightly wrong (actually, several errors). It's a prompt for you to correct it

Comment: @MukeshKalgude: give space after join and ( and change one alaias as b instead of both a.

Comment: Yes. Those are some of the errors.

Answer (score -1):

try below to get latest row (your query will provide only latest date in date column but not latest record)-

```
select student,grade,entry_time 
from (select student,grade,entry_time from records order by entry_time desc) a group by student
```

Comment: may i know the reason of -ve vote.

Comment: Your solution relies upon an undocumented behaviour of MySQL (one which recent documentation suggests will be unavailable in the future)

Comment: i know it is not good solution for bulky tables but it will provide desired results if your table size is no too large. It can be a concern related with optimization but we can't say that it is not a solution.

Comment: The problem is not (primarily) about optimization. It's about guaranteeing the return of a correct result. While, in practice, all recent versions (pre 5.6 anyway) may return the expected result. The indication is that this will not continue.

Comment: @Strawberry: may you let me know (just for my knowledge) what can be change in next version as here no any specific function is using that functionality can be change here we are just doing reverse ordering in sub-query and then fetching results from this sub-query.

Comment: You're grouping the subquery on the assumption that this will net the 'first' row result for each student. While in practice that may work, according to the documentation, this behaviour cannot be guaranteed.